# 1-D convolution in Character-level CNN

Tags: machine-learning

In 2015 LeCun proposed the Character-level CNN in the paper  *Text Understanding from Scratch*.

I am quite confused by the model description in the following figure.[image]

Can someone help me to figure out why after the first convolution the height of the matrix becomes larger? It does not make any sense to me.

Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convolutional layers typically learn multiple kernels, each of which will produce a different output vector after processing the input.

[Here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) you can see a neat moving example for 2-dimensional, 3-channel input, which is a typical setting for computer vision (RGB images). Two filters are learned, so two output matrices result. Adding a new kernel would result in a third matrix being output.

The illustration you provide suggests three kernels being learned for the input, resulting in a three-fold increase in dimensionality (that's just in the figure, though. The real network probably uses a different number of kernels, and certainly larger input). The new output frames could be regarded as separate channels, or concatenated (as the figure suggests). This last approach would require wider kernels.